# Validation on list within the same period

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We have SharePoint list to register the employee sick absence, the HR user sometime register duplicate absence   or in the within the same absence   period   for the same employee, example the following record  :

- Name : Tony
- ID :400
- Sick Leave start_date 3/27/2018 AM
- Sick Leave end_date 3/29/2018 AM
- Total days : 3

per the example by mistake the HR user add new sick leave for tony on 3/28/2018  without he notice he already take a leave from 3/27/2018 to 3/29/2018 .

So the question How we can add validation to restrict adding record in the same absence period

Comment: Is this a custom solution with server side object model ?

Comment: In CSOM , you can add event receivers and check for these validations in `ItemAdding` event. But using OOTB features i dont think validating one item based on another item is possible

Comment: no its not a  custom solution ... its standard list and they direct add records

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PreSaveAction` to do client side custom validation,so you could use REST api or JSOM to query whether user has apply a request already, when return false, the list item won't save.

Check the sample [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx)